# Integration bound using ML forumla

Tags: complex-analysis

> Show using ML formula that $$\left|\int_{\gamma}e^{iz^2}\operatorname{d}z\right|\leq \frac{\pi(e-1)}{4e},$$ where $\;\;\gamma:\gamma(t)=e^{it}; \;\;\;0\leq t\leq \frac{\pi}{4}.$

Here $L(\gamma)=\frac{\pi}{4}$, and I need to show $$M=\max_{t\in[0,\pi/4]}|f(\gamma(t))|=1-e^{-1},$$ so using $$\left|e^{i(x(t)+iy(t))^2}\right|=e^{-2x(t)y(t)}$$ and $\sin 2t \geq \frac{4t}{\pi}$ in $t\in[0,\pi/4]$, I have arrived at $$\max_{t\in[0,\pi/4]}|e^{-\sin 2t}|\leq e^{-4t/\pi}.$$ But I am struggling to find the desired $M=1-e^{-1}$ from here. Some hints are appreciated.

Comment: You cannot do that, since$$\left|\int_\gamma e^{z^2}\,\mathrm dz\right|\approx1.35076\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{\pi(e-1)}{4e}\approx0.496466.$$

Comment: Also, the max cannot be $1-1/e$ since $t=0$ ($z=1$) gives $e$.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos My bad it should be $e^{iz^2}$, corrected.

Comment: That's better, but it is still false that you always have $\bigl|f\bigl(\gamma(t)\bigr)\bigr|\leqslant1-e^{-1}$ for each $t\in\left[0,\frac\pi4\right]$.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos Then no way to show it via ML? I can show the required bound by just integrating: $\int_0^{\pi/4} e^{-\sin 2t}dt \leq \int_0^{\pi/4} e^{-4t/\pi}dt=\frac{\pi(e-1)}{4e}$ however the question specifically asks to use ML.

Comment: I don't see how it can be done.